# Content security policy header - both upgrade insecure requests and report the events

Tags: .htaccess, content-security-policy, response-headers

What I'm trying to achieve: **Both upgrade all HTTP requests within the page to HTTPS and report/log the events.**

The server supports both HTTP and HTTPS.

Test HTML page. Note the hardcoded HTTP protocol in `<img>`

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://example.com/testimage.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

According to the [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/upgrade-insecure-requests/#reporting-upgrades), I set up my .htaccess like this:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests; default-src https:"
Header set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src https:; report-uri https://report-uri.io/report/..."
```

When I call https://example.com/testpage.html, it loads the image over HTTPS but doesn't report the event.

What am I missing?

Comment: what browser are you using? perhaps the browser does not support it?

Comment: I don't see a violation report in Chrome or Firefox (by checking the dev console)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if `upgrade-insecure-requests` or `block-all-mixed-content` will generated events because they prevent the bad events from happening in the first place.

I could be wrong about the reasoning, but I do know `block-all-mixed-content` does not generate violations.

For block-all-mixed-content, it explicitely will not send a report. From https://www.w3.org/TR/mixed-content/#strict-opt-in:

> This directive has no effect when monitored. This directive’s only
>   effect is to set a policy flag on the protected resource; it will
>   therefore never be violated, and has no reporting requirements.